# Define struct array in function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The code:

```
int i;
struct st
{
    int m;
}st_t[2];

void foo()
{
    i = 4;
    st_t[2] = 
    {
       {10},{20}
    };  // it's wrong !!!!  but I don't know how to do.     
}
int main()
{
   foo();
   cout<<i<<endl;          // will output 4;
   cout<<st_t[0].m<<endl;  // this should output 10
   cout<<st_t[1].m<<endl;  // this should output 20

   return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to define a struct array in a function? If it is, then how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

PS:
Sorry my English is not good. I am making a Tetris game, it have a Shape class, I declared a shape struct array in Shape.h, then I assign to the struct array in Shape constructor function in Shape.cpp. Is it right? or how to assign to the struct array so I can use it in another function?

Comment: From the code, it looks like you're trying to assign to the global array, not define an array in a function. Which do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the direct assignment of values, you can initialize a temporary variable and copy this variable to your global variable:

Delete:

```
 ...
 st_t[2] =  {
      {10},{20}
 };
 ...
```

and add:

```
 ...
 st tmp[2] = { {10}, {20} };  

 memcpy(st_t, tmp, sizeof st_t);
 ...
```

**Addendum:**

If it doesn't work for you, there might be another error in your code. From your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory.h>
using namespace std;

 int i;
 struct st { int m; } st_t[2];

 void foo()
{
 i = 4;
 st tmp[2] = { {10}, {20} }; 
 memcpy(st_t, tmp, sizeof st_t); // use: const_addr instead of &const_addr
}

 int main()
{
 foo();
 cout << i << endl;          // will output 4;
 cout << st_t[0].m << endl;  // this should output 10
 cout << st_t[1].m << endl;  // this should output 20
 return 0;
}
```

all works fine as expected.

Comment: It doesn't work. The output from main function is always `0` .

Comment: I tried it for you. The output is `4,10,20`. See my addendum.

Answer (score 2):

You can *initialize* an array in the place where it's defined. I.e. either move the definition into the function, or move the initialization out of the function:

```
struct st 
{ 
    int m; 
} 
st_t[2] = {{10},{20}};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define an array in the function (as your question title and text implies), then add the type specifier `st` to the definition:

```
st st_t[2] = 
{
   {10},{20}
};
```

However, this will be a separate array to the global one, and so the output from `main()` won't match what your comments say should happen. If you actually want to assign to the global array, then:

```
st_t[0].m = 10;
st_t[1].m = 20;
```

or, in C++11, you can use similar syntax to your example if you replace the plain array with `std::array`:

```
std::array<st, 2> st_t;

void foo() {
    // Note the extra braces - std::array is an aggregate containing an array
    st_t = 
    {{
        {10},{20}
    }};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is helpful to me, but not solved my problem. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the variable at function scope then

```
void foo() {
    struct {
        int m;
    } st_t = { {10}, {20} };
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Your sample would not be compiled successfully, there are more initializers than members.